# SOQL aggregate functions do not work with Task.ActivityDate

Tags: soql, tasks, event, aggregate, group-by

When I try the following in the Query Editor of the Developer Console:

```
SELECT WhoID, COUNT(Id), MIN(ActivityDate), MAX(ActivityDate)
FROM Task
GROUP BY WhoID
LIMIT 1000
```

I get the following error:

```
SELECT WhoID, COUNT(Id), MIN(ActivityDate), MAX(ActivityDate)
                         ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
field ActivityDate does not support aggregate operator MIN
```

One would think that, given that `Task.ActivityDate` is a field of type Date, it should be possible to calculate the minimum/maximum value.

Actually, according to Salesforce's documentation on [**Support for Field Types in Aggregate Functions**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions_field_types.htm), the use of `MIN()` and `MAX()` with DateTime is allowed.

At least I know I am not alone, [there is a post in Ideas about it](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lJtWQAU).

Any idea on how I can make this work?

Comment: N.B. per the doc on Task, `ActivityDate` is of type Date but your question is still a good one!

Comment: @cropredy: The plot thickens. If you go to the Object Manager, `ActivityDate` appears as "Date/Time". I went by that instead of opening the object in the Developer Console. Amended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a workaround by creating a custom field of type date under the `Activity` object called `ActivityDate__c`. Thus we can reformulate the initial query as

```
SELECT WhoID, COUNT(Id), MIN(ActivityDate__c), MAX(ActivityDate__c)
FROM Task
GROUP BY WhoID
LIMIT 1000
```

It is not ideal, but it's not the first time that I have had to hack around the `Task`/`Event`/`Activity` object to make things work as they should.

I am going to consider turning it into a "trigger formula" that gets updated before insert/update, and make the field visible only when the code is executing in G-d mode.

Comment: creating a formula field and then use this formula field for min/max, that worked. thanks!